# Edit document properties in MS-Word 2016

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am currently trying to setup a template where the user is prompted to add "tags" to their document when they open a new MS-Word file. Currently I have broken this down in a few parts.

1. Startup prompt
2. Connect the document/script to the "tag" property (so the user don't have to manually change it)
3. Ideally implement a drop-down menu, so I don't accidentally tag some files with small differences such as spaces, case sensitive formating etc.

Currently I have tried most of what Word has to offer, which is why I came here. The easiest answer is to go in "File -> Information -> Tags" and edit this manually, but this is what I hope to automate. I have used the feature "Quick Parts", where I can add a field which edits properties such as "Author", "Tags" etc. The problem here is that they are not customizable, so I can not implement a drop-down menu. I have tried to use the "Developer" section in Word to add controllers such as drop-down menus, but I have not found a way to connect these to the document properties. I also tried using the FILLIN command to see if it could be used as shown below, just to test if I could set these properties from the document in this way.

```
{ SET bkmTitle { TITLE { FILLIN "Enter the document title" } } }
```

The problem with this implementation is that I don't want to press F9 in these fields when I start up a new project. I have not done much research into the startup prompt because I see this as the finishing touch, but if anyone has any advice on that too, it would be greatly appreciated.

I don't have any experience with macros/VBA, but I am open to learn if that is the easiest way to realize this project. Thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: Look into my page on customizing these content controls. https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart You can use tags or titles on content controls to identify them. See also http://www.gmayor.com/Userform.htm.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to make a system so I can easily organize my documents when I save them. It could be through the "tag" or "category" or any other document property of course.

For the second part, yes to that one as well. I tend to forget the way I format things, so if I were to tag something as "homework", "Homework", "home-work", "home_work" etc. I would end up having to write a pretty elaborate script to predict myself when trying to fetch different categories

Comment: Thank you so much Charles! Although I am not experienced with XML, the links definitly gives me something to work from. Will see where this leads :)

Answer (score 0):

From Charles Kenyon's links I solved my problem with Quick Parts. My solution was to extract the .docx file so I could access the .xml file within. Inside the .docx file (also works with the .dotm template file found in /AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Templates). Using 7-zip I opened the .dotm archive and went on word -> document.xml.

I made a template by editing the Normal.dotm (MS-Word template file). Here I added a Quick Part for "Category", then saved the template. I then opened the .xml file as mentioned above where I could edit this Quick Part for the template from textfield to a drop down menu (was not possible to change in Word to my knowledge).

To change it into other types than drop down menu, it is possible to add other control forms from Word by clicking on the "Developer" tab and selecting other controls such as "Checkbox". When you open the "document.xml" file afterwards, you can now see the schema for a checkbox.

When editing the "Document Properties" style Quick Parts, they are automatically linked to the document properties, which is what I wanted to learn how to do. It is probably possible to also use the document.xml file to explore how to link other fields to the document properties. I hope this answer might help others if they want to explore more options in MS-Word.